# How can a pion with neutral charge exist?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks, pions

A $\pi^0$ consists of an up and anti-up quark. However, I also learned that when a particle and its anti-particle meet, energy is produced.

So, my question is that how can $\pi^0$ exist? Won't it turn to energy instantly if it is formed?

Comment: It does, although it might take several nanoseconds. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion.

Comment: The crucial part that is missing in the duplicate's answer is that the annihilation must go through either the weak or the electromagnetic interaction. This is because even though quark and antiquark are continually created by and destroyed into gluons the strong force is such that it binds all strongly interacting particles in a "bag". So an annihilation into gluons is "more of the same" for the neutral pion. It takes the electromagnetic to annihilate the quarks.

Comment: The charged pions cannot do the same because charge is conserved and it takes the weak interaction for a pi- to decay into a mu and two neutrinos. for the feynman diagrams see for pi0 http://www-zeus.physik.uni-bonn.de/~brock/feynman/vtp_ss06/chapter02/pi0decay.jpg for pi- http://www-zeus.physik.uni-bonn.de/~brock/feynman/vtp_ws0506/chapter02/pimu_decay.jpg . The electromagnetic is many orders of magnitude larger than the weak and that is why it comes first in pi0